# Rails 3: dynamic route depending on parameter value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to match the same url to two different controllers depending on a url parameter. This is the result I am looking for:

```
/feed?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2
```

match /genres if foo2 == bar2

```
/feed
```

match /movies

Both routes should default to rss.

Tried the following configuration, however routes always match the first rule and won't hit the second genre rule.

> match '/feed(:foo2)' => 'movies#index', :as => :movies, :defaults => {
>   :format => 'rss' }, :constraints => [ :foo2 => "/bar2/" ]
>
> match
>   '/feed' => 'genres#index', :as => :genres, :defaults => { :format =>
>   'rss' }

Any ideas on how to do something like this?

Comment: You should be able to solve this with a constraint class (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints), but handling this in your controller action might be the simplest solution.

Comment: I added a feed controller to catch request and render the correct view etc. Thanks :)